# Inserting nested array data into the database table

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

Trying to insert data obtained from an API; it comes in a nested array. Main one "data" which includes id and type, and in some instances has a "breakdown" array which includes 3 cols, label percentage and count.

I'm trying to insert this straight into the database; however it does not appreciate the breakdown array being absent for some of the ids when running through for each loop (there are 2 loops one for data array and the last for breakdown array).

Tried adding the following expression:

```
if
(
  equals(items('For_each')?['breakdown'], null), 
  json('[]'), 
  items('For_each')?['breakdown']
)
```

This has stopped failing the Logic App, however it just inserts records with the breakdown array only and ignores all the other ones without it.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Additional info, example payload used:

```
{
"result_ok": true,
"total_count": 0,
"page": 1,
"total_pages": 1,
"results_per_page": 0,
"data": [
{
"id": 22,
"type": "INSTRUCTIONS"
},
{
"id": 26,
"type": "INSTRUCTIONS"
},
{
"id": 24,
"type": "INSTRUCTIONS"
},
{
"id": 25,
"type": "INSTRUCTIONS"
},
{
"id": 3,
"type": "IMAGE_SELECT",
"breakdown": [
{
"label": "Agree",
"percentage": "34.6",
"count": "256"
},
{
"label": "Neither agree nor disagree",
"percentage": "30.9",
"count": "229"
},
{
"label": "Strongly agree",
"percentage": "17.6",
"count": "130"
},
{
"label": "Disagree",
"percentage": "12.2",
"count": "90"
},
{
"label": "Strongly disagree",
"percentage": "4.7",
"count": "35"
}
],
"total responses": "740",
"sum": "0",
"average": 0,
"stdDev": null,
"min": null,
"max": null
},
{
"id": 6,
"type": "IMAGE_SELECT",
"breakdown": [
{
"label": "Agree",
"percentage": "41.9",
"count": "309"
},
{
"label": "Strongly agree",
"percentage": "25.4",
"count": "187"
},
{
"label": "Neither agree nor disagree",
"percentage": "19.8",
"count": "146"
},
{
"label": "Disagree",
"percentage": "9.6",
"count": "71"
},
{
"label": "Strongly disagree",
"percentage": "3.3",
"count": "24"
}
],
"total responses": "737",
"sum": "0",
"average": 0,
"stdDev": null,
"min": null,
"max": null
},
{
"id": 5,
"type": "IMAGE_SELECT",
"breakdown": [
{
"label": "Agree",
"percentage": "28.1",
"count": "208"
},
{
"label": "Neither agree nor disagree",
"percentage": "27.6",
"count": "204"
},
{
"label": "Strongly agree",
"percentage": "18.6",
"count": "138"
},
{
"label": "Disagree",
"percentage": "14.3",
"count": "106"
},
{
"label": "Strongly disagree",
"percentage": "11.4",
"count": "84"
}
],
"total responses": "740",
"sum": "0",
"average": 0,
"stdDev": null,
"min": null,
"max": null
},
{
"id": 7,
"type": "IMAGE_SELECT",
"breakdown": [
{
"label": "Agree",
"percentage": "39.1",
"count": "288"
},
{
"label": "Neither agree nor disagree",
"percentage": "23.7",
"count": "175"
},
{
"label": "Strongly agree",
"percentage": "23.5",
"count": "173"
},
{
"label": "Disagree",
"percentage": "9.6",
"count": "71"
},
{
"label": "Strongly disagree",
"percentage": "4.1",
"count": "30"
}
],
"total responses": "737",
"sum": "0",
"average": 0,
"stdDev": null,
"min": null,
"max": null
},
{
"id": 33,
"type": "IMAGE_SELECT",
"breakdown": [
{
"label": "Agree",
"percentage": "39.1",
"count": "286"
},
{
"label": "Strongly agree",
"percentage": "24.6",
"count": "180"
},
{
"label": "Neither agree nor disagree",
"percentage": "24.3",
"count": "178"
},
{
"label": "Disagree",
"percentage": "7.7",
"count": "56"
},
{
"label": "Strongly disagree",
"percentage": "4.4",
"count": "32"
}
],
"total responses": "732",
"sum": "0",
"average": 0,
"stdDev": null,
"min": null,
"max": null
},
{
"id": 12,
"type": "ESSAY"
},
{
"id": 13,
"type": "CHECKBOX",
"breakdown": [

],
"total responses": null,
"sum": null,
"average": null,
"stdDev": "0.00",
"min": "0.0",
"max": "0.0"
},
{
"id": 1,
"type": "INSTRUCTIONS"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to modify the current item with the properties by adding the absent properties to the current item with null/empty values. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

Flow inside `For each` loop

[image]

Results:

[image]

[image]

Below is the complete codeview of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Current_Item": {
                        "inputs": "@union(outputs('Template'),items('For_each'))",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    },
                    "Insert_row_(V2)": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                "average": "@outputs('Current_Item')['average']",
                                "breakdown": "@{string(outputs('Current_Item')['breakdown'])}",
                                "id": "@outputs('Current_Item')['id']",
                                "max": "@outputs('Current_Item')['max']",
                                "min": "@outputs('Current_Item')['min']",
                                "stdDev": "@outputs('Current_Item')['stdDev']",
                                "sum": "@outputs('Current_Item')['sum']",
                                "total_responses": "@outputs('Current_Item')['total responses']",
                                "type": "@{outputs('Current_Item')['type']}"
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[data]'))}/items"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Current_Item": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@json(triggerBody())['data']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Template": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Template": {
                "inputs": {
                    "average": null,
                    "breakdown": [],
                    "max": "0.0",
                    "min": "0.0",
                    "stdDev": "0.00",
                    "sum": null,
                    "total responses": null
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subid>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, just used some sql to normalise that breakdown column!